# How to declare two ng-change function together

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to ask that I am trying to implement the phonechange and emailchange function together. I am trying to call the function like if the phonechange function and emailchange function is true it will alert me that the phone number and email you enter is valid. Will be very appreciate for your guys help

```
$scope.phone = {data: ""};
$scope.email = {data: ""};
$scope.FirstName = {data: ""};
$scope.LastName = {data: ""};



$scope.phonechange = function (){
  phone = this.phone.data;
if(PHONE_REGEXP.test(this.phone.data)){
  alert('phone true');

  $scope.invalid = false;
}else{
  console.log('false');
    $scope.invalid = true;

}

}

$scope.emailchange = function(){
  if(re.test(this.email.data)){
  alert('email true');
    $scope.invalid = false;

}else{
  console.log('false');
    $scope.invalid = true;

}
}
```

Comment: please indent your code

Answer (score 2):

Add a function for each input:

```
<input name="phone" ng-model="phone" ng-change="phoneChange()"/>
<input name="email" ng-model="email" ng-change="emailChange()"/>
```

Controller (just suggestion for you):

```
$scope.phone = '';
$scope.email = '';
$scope.firstName = '';
$scope.lastName = '';

$scope.isvalid = {
  phone: true,
  email: true
};


$scope.phonechange = function (){

  $scope.isvalid.phone = PHONE_REGEXP.test($scope.phone) // true|false;

  if ($scope.isvalid.phone) {
    // Do something
  }

};

$scope.emailchange = function(){
  $scope.isvalid.email = re.test($scope.email);

  if ($scope.isvalid.email) {
    // Do something
  }
};
```

But, you can use `ng-pattern` for validating. Check more [here](https://www.bookdoc.com/registration/)

Comment: Hi @WorkWe what if I want if $scope.isvalid.email && $scope.isvalid.phone together and then only execute a statement

Comment: We should use 2 variables about `is/invalid data` to know error for each input. As I said above, you can use `ng-pattern` with HTML5 to check form is valid, just use `if (formName.$isvalid) {//}`

Comment: Thanks for your help @WorkWe the ng-pattern works so sorry for the late reply